# Sort isotope between asc to desc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-isotope

im working on a project with isotope sorting and ordering a table between rows and also the use of history! This code i got from someone else over the internet and adapted to my needs!

As i am more a designer than coder, im having trouble to sort order between asc to desc from a toggle click in the same sort button..

Everything i try, mess with the code.. so for here is the working code i have:
http://jsfiddle.net/uiliw/grmL5Los/

what im trying to do is to toggle sortAscending between click to each sort button:

```
// Initialize Isotope
       $container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          layoutMode: 'vertical',
          getSortData: {
                  codigo: '.codigo  parseFloat',
                  titulo: '.titulo',
                  versao: '.versao  parseFloat',
                  emissor: '.emissor  parseFloat',
                  situacao: '.situacao',
              },
        sortAscending: {
                codigo: sortCodigo,
                titulo: sortTitulo,
                versao: sortVersao,
                emissor: sortEmissor,
                situacao: sortSituacao,

      }

        });
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this?!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sortBy](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/sorting.html#sortby_option) and [sortAscending](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/sorting.html#sortascending_option) in your isotope arguments.

```
    // Initialize Isotope
    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      layoutMode: 'vertical',
      getSortData: {
              codigo: '.codigo  parseFloat',
              titulo: '.titulo',
              versao: '.versao  parseFloat',
              emissor: '.emissor  parseFloat',
              situacao: '.situacao',
          },
     sortBy : 'codigo',
     sortAscending : false
    });
```

**sortBy** should be one of the property name values in the **getSortData** list:
`codigo`, `titulo`, `versao`, `emisso` or `situacao`

**sortAscending** you can toggle between `true` and `false`, depending on the direction you desire.  A value of `false` will make it sort descending.

**Documentation:** http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/sorting.html

Comment: i got this already, the thing is how can i change true to false or false to true clicking on the same sort button.. like... if i click on codigo once, the table sort to ascending related to codigo, than if i click again, it sort to descending... thats why i inserted sortCodigo, sortTitulo and so on.. cause i think i could do a function to switch between true and false to each one everytime i click on one link... would be nice to help me adjusting on my jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uiliw/grmL5Los/) .. Ahhh... im using Isotope **v2**!!

Comment: this is exactly what im trying to do, but this is **V1**, i need to work with **v2** [http://jsfiddle.net/uiliw/LNRzZ/127/](http://jsfiddle.net/uiliw/LNRzZ/127/)